# Subclass object of pathlib.Path gets custom attributes lost after pickle.load

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, serialization, pickle

```
from pathlib import Path
import pickle
class P(type(Path())):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = ''
p = P()
p.a = 'x'
with open('xx', 'wb') as wf:
    pickle.dump(p, wf)
p1 = pickle.load(open('xx', 'rb'))
print(p1.a)            # here p1.a is ''
```

I am making a subclass of `pathlib.Path` and like to add some custom attributes to it.
The problem is that the custom attribute gets lost after reloaded by pickle.
How to solve this problem.

Other solutions I tried:

- use `__slots__`, the same issue.
- use composition instead of inheritance, then dispatch Path-like methods by implementing `__getattr__`. However, in this case, `self.path` is not initialized within `pickle.load` thus causing an endless call of `__getattr__`.

```
class File():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.path = Path(*args)
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.path, item)
p = File('aaa')
p.exists()  # no error
with open('xx', 'wb') as wf:
    pickle.dump(p, wf)
p1 = pickle.load(open('xx', 'rb')) 
# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded. 
# This is due to call of self.path, in that moment, path is not in self.__dict__
```

Comment: WHOOPs nvm, I got that backward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For the problem of the inheritance one.

Another solution as a note to @martineau’s answer.

If I'm correct, the problem is caused by the `__reduce__` method in `pathlib.PosixPath`. It seems like that the pickle behavior will be determined by this method. and @martineau's solution which uses `copyreg.pickle(P, pickle_P)` is also related to this method: `pickle_P` has the same return pattern as `__reduce__`.

Here is the doc about return values of [`__reduce__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__):

> When a tuple is returned, it must be between two and six items long.
> Optional items can either be omitted, or None can be provided as their
> value. The semantics of each item are in order:
>
> - A callable object that will be called to create the initial version of the object.
> - A tuple of arguments for the callable object. An empty tuple must be given if the callable does not accept any argument.
> - Optionally, the object’s state, which will be passed to the object’s `__setstate__()` method as previously described. If the object has no such method then, the value must be a dictionary and it will be added
>   to the object’s `__dict__` attribute.
> - ...

The second item explains how does @martineau's solution works: the second return value will be passed into `__init__`.

And this is the source code of `PosixPath.__reduce__`

```py
    def __reduce__(self):
        # Using the parts tuple helps share interned path parts
        # when pickling related paths.
        # self._parts is arguments passed to Path
        return (self.__class__, tuple(self._parts))
```

According to the description of the third return value, the solution is:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pickle
class P(type(Path())):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = ''
    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, tuple(self._parts), self.__dict__

p = P()
p.a = 'x'
with open('xx', 'wb') as wf:
    pickle.dump(p, wf)
p1 = pickle.load(open('xx', 'rb'))
print(p1.a)            # here p1.a is 'x'
```

Shortcomings of this solution:

- P's instance will contain a `__dict__` attribute (`Path` uses `__slots__`).
- attribute named `_hash` will be ignored.

#### For the problem of the composition one

A note in the doc of [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) may explain the cause of the error.

> Note At unpickling time, some methods like `__getattr__()`,
> `__getattribute__()`, or `__setattr__()` may be called upon the instance. In case those methods rely on some internal invariant being true, the
> type should implement `__new__()` to establish such an invariant, as
> `__init__()` is not called when unpickling an instance.

To ensure `path` attribute exits when calling `__getattr__`, a solution is to move the attribute assignment into `__new__` method (before `__init__`).

```py
class File():
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        obj = super().__new__(cls)
        obj.path = Path(*args)
        return obj
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.path, item)
p = File('aaa')
p.exists()  # no error
with open('xx', 'wb') as wf:
    pickle.dump(p, wf)
p1 = pickle.load(open('xx', 'rb')) # no error
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be by using the [`copyreg`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copyreg.html) module to associate a pickle support function to instance of your class as shown below. Note I also had to modify how your `P` class handles arguments — it no longer ignores them.

```
import copyreg
from pathlib import Path
import pickle


class P(type(Path())):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = args[0] if args else ''


def pickle_P(p):
    print("pickling a P instance...")
    return P, (p.a,)

copyreg.pickle(P, pickle_P)

p = P()
p.a = 'x'
q = P('y')

with open('xx', 'wb') as outp:
    pickle.dump(p, outp)
    pickle.dump(q, outp)

with open('xx', 'rb') as inp:
    p1 = pickle.load(inp)
    q1 = pickle.load(inp)

print('p1.a = {!r}'.format(p1.a))
print('q1.a = {!r}'.format(q1.a))
```

Output:

```
pickling a P instance...
pickling a P instance...
p1.a = 'x'
q1.a = 'y'
```

Comment: What about the composition one? if that error can also be solved in this manner. I checked the doc of `copyreg` but there are no descriptions of how to write the support function.

Comment: As I said this is one way to do it. For one thing, the helper function could have been implemented in a different manner plus there are other ways to doing something like this that don't involve using the `copyreg` module at all. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by a compositional one. If that's an important aspect, mention and add a (better) description of it to your question.

Comment: thanks, I mean the situation in the second code example.

Comment: I think the problem with a compositional approach is knowing (or somehow determining) what attributes have been added to the instance so they can be saved and later restored by `pickle`. I'm not saying I think it's impossible, but am still not clear about exactly what you're trying accomplish much less why it has to be done in a certain way.

Comment: I am trying to make a class with the same interface as `pathlib.Path`.

Comment: The subclass you defined doesn't support the arguments the `Path` class accepts, so that part of its interface is already broken. Regardless, as I've already tried to explain, the added attributes must either be known in advance (i.e. hardcodable) or somehow be able to be discovered/determined when instances of the subclass are pickled and un-pickled.

Comment: One approach might to have a naming convention for all added attributes and to iterate through a subclass instances' `__dict__` and search for those that match the pattern. Another would be to have a single extra known attribute with a unique name, like `_extra_stuff`, that was a dictionary containing the names and values of the all the other additional attributes. Lastly, if the number of extra things is small and fixed, then just simply hardcode them — basically what my answer is doing for one named `a`.